# Discord.js buttons error (TypeError: INVALID_BUTTON_STYLE: An invalid button styles was provided)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, discord-buttons

I was try to use discord-buttons. and I was make some code and run it. but it wasn't work
That was error in buttons style code.
I'm use discord.js 12-, and made button with discord-button
I don't know how to solve this problem. What I should do?

this is error

```
the bot is online!
C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\discord-buttons\src\v12\Util.js:13
      throw new TypeError('INVALID_BUTTON_STYLE: An invalid button styles was provided');
            ^

TypeError: INVALID_BUTTON_STYLE: An invalid button styles was provided
    at resolveStyle (C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\discord-buttons\src\v12\Util.js:13:13)
    at MessageButton.setStyle (C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\discord-buttons\src\v12\Classes\MessageButton.js:31:13)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\index.js:28:14)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle ot(C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket ot(C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage ot(C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Downloads\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
```

and this is my code

```
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const Database = require("./Helpers/Database");
const { MessageButton } = require('discord-buttons')
```

.....

```
    let button1 = new MessageButton()
        .setLabel("test1")
        .setStyle('ORANGE')
        .setID("button1")
    let button2 = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle('BLURPLE')
        .setLabel("test2")
        .setID("button2")
    let button3 = new MessageButton()
        .setStyle('gray')
        .setLabel("test3")
        .setID("button3")
```

.....

```
    message.author.send({embed: embed, buttons: [button1, button2, button3]})
```

Comment: please check the official docs first https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton?scrollTo=setCustomId

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://discord-buttons.js.org/docs/stable/examples/buttons.html#multiple-buttons), they use grey with the 'e'. Not an 'a'. Simple mistake that can be easily corrected

```js
let button3 = new MessageButton()
  .setStyle('grey') //not 'gray'
  .setLabel("test3")
  .setID("button3")
```

Note: this package is deprecated with the release of discord.js v13. There are some other packages like `discord-reply` which are also deprecated as v13 has support for buttons and replies.

Comment: I was change gray to grey. but it didn't work. Can't I use discord-botton in discord v12?

Comment: I think it is not compatible with v13